# Multidimensional Array - Pulling Data

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

New to PHP and after spending hours researching on here, nothing seems to be exactly what I need. I have a multi dimensional array that I'm looking to pull data and COUNT from. FOR Instance:

```
array (
  'loyola' => NULL,
  'gold_coast' => NULL,
  'lincolnpark' => 
  array (
    0 => 'Building 1',
    1 => 'Building 2',
    2 => 'Building 3',
    3 => 'Building 4'
  ),
  'lakeview' => 
  array (
    0 => 'Building 1',
    1 => 'Building 2',
    2 => 'Building 3'

  ),
)
```

I'm looking to essentially create a table that lists all the buildings and in the next column the number of times that building appears.

This what I've gotten thus far, but it only displays all buildings.

```
$buildings = unserialize($row['buildings']);
$lincolnpark = $buildings['lincolnpark'];
$loyola= $buildings['loyola'];
$gold_coast = $buildings['gold_coast'];
$lakeview = $buildings['lakeview'];

foreach ($lakeview as $value)
{                       
    echo $value;
}
}
```

Comment: first column simply lists all the buildings from a specific area, and the second column lists all the areas a specific building is in? is that right?

Comment: what does your expected output look like ?

Comment: First column just lists all buildings, regardless of area, second column counts how many times each building appears total.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below. It will navigate recursively into the array and will print the qtd each build appear.

```
<?php


$arr = array (
        'loyola' => NULL,
        'gold_coast' => NULL,
        'lincolnpark' =>
        array (
                0 => 'Building 1',
                1 => 'Building 2',
                2 => 'Building 3',
                3 => 'Building 4'
        ),
        'lakeview' =>
        array (
                0 => 'Building 1',
                1 => 'Building 2',
                2 => 'Building 3'

        ),
);
$ret = array();

countBuildings($arr);

foreach($ret as $key=>$value){
    echo "Building: $key ==> qtd : $value <br>";
}
function countBuildings($arr = array()){
    global $ret;
    foreach($arr as $value){
        if(is_array($value)){
            countBuildings($value);
        }else{
            if($value != NULL){
                if(isset($ret[$value])){
                    $ret[$value] += 1;
                }else{
                    $ret[$value] = 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it in two passes: one for counting building occurrences in a separate array, and another for output.